# excel : index results from two columns and double them

Tags: excel

I have two columns of numbers, F:G and I need them to both be indexed in column K, and also doubled. Results in column K should be : f64; f64; g64; g64; f65; f65; g65; g65... and so on

I have the logic of doubling the results, but not of indexing both columns

```
=IF(N64="",F65,IF(N64<>N63,N64,IF(MOD(ROW(),4),INDEX($G$64:G65,SMALL(ROW($64:$92),ROW(F65) +0.5),INDEX($F$64:$F65,SMALL(ROW($64:$92),ROW(F65)))))))
```

I have tried calculating the formula as an array also, but without success. I'm open to writing a quick macro for this, but would really prefer if a formula could do the trick, is it possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what the rest of your formula is about but this will give you the pattern you want:

```
=INDEX(F:G,INT((ROW(1:1)-1)/4)+64,INT(MOD((ROW(1:1)-1),4)/2)+1)
```

Where the `+64` is your starting row.

[image]